# uintptr_t is too small to store addresses

Tags: c

In C, when I cast a pointer to type uintptr_t, it truncates part of the address. Is there anyway to store the entire address as an integer or some other data type that is no larger than 8 bytes?

Comment: It may be smaller than a pointer only in architectures with segmented memory...is it your case?

Comment: "when I cast a pointer to type uintptr_t, it truncates part of the address". Are you sure that is what is happening and that you haven't misunderstood the results? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `uintptr_t` must store the whole address, according to the C Standard. Probably you have a bug in your code somewhere

Comment: Are you converting object pointers or function pointers?  If the compiler defines `uintptr_t`, it must be able to represent any pointer to an object (a `void *`) accurately without loss of information (a round trip conversion from `void *` to `uintptr_t` and back to `void *` must not lose information).  Pointers to functions do not have to fit into the type, though (but it is an unusual machine where they don't).

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using an IBM AS/400 or iSeries machine?

Comment: Usually those who program AS/400 or iSeries, would probably have someone else besides stackoverflow to ask from.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you're facing there, as `uintpt_t` should usually be large enough to hold *any* pointer; if the type exists, it must be large enough to hold a `void *` and therefore any pointer to any object (C11 draft n1570 7.20.1.4):

> The  following  type  designates  an  unsigned  integer  type  with  the  property that any valid pointer to void
>   can  be  converted  to  this  type,  then  converted  back  to  pointer  to
>   void,
>   and the result will compare equal to the original pointer:
>
> `uintptr_t`
>
> [this type is optional]

Notably there is **no guarantee that a pointer-to-function** can be converted to `uintptr_t` and back again portably, though this would be the case on POSIX.

---

Additionally the C standard does not **guarantee** that there is **any** integer type at all that is large enough to contain a pointer on an implementation; however, if the type `uintptr_t` exists, then this wouldn't be the case (the `uintptr_t` type is the type that's big enough).